# Android Button internal onClick actions

Tags: android

I'm making a custom button which is designed to handle onClick events internally. Here's a simplified version of my implementation:

```
public class CustomButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener {
    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setText("Clicked!");
    }
}
```

No surprises in the above code! The problem is that the activity/fragment/whatever containing the button could call `setOnClickListener(View)` which would prevent the `onClick(View)` method inside the button from receiving the onClick event, thus changing the function of my button in an undesirable way. I though about overriding `setOnClickListener(View)` to throw an exception if the argument is not `this`, but I don't want to prevent the button from having external listeners, I just want to add an internal feature.

Which method of `Button` if any can I override to do extra stuff when the button is clicked without taking away the ability of other classes to listen to onClick events? Basically, which method in `Button` dispatches `OnClick` events?

Comment: The `Button` does not dispatch `OnClick` events, the system does.

Comment: The button must receive the on click event in some way tho, because its appearance is changed.

Comment: The visual part of the Button receives a state change, and it draws itself in `android:state_pressed` state. But that has nothing to do with the `Button`'s code, but rather it's selector. [Feel free to read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) if you already haven't.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a solution. I made `CustomButton` as follows:

```
public class CustomButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener {
    private OnClickListener externalOnClickListener;   

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        super.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        super.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttrs) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttrs);
        super.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do all of my stuff
        setText("Clicked!");
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        // Pass onClick event to external listener
        if (externalOnClickListener != null) {            
            externalOnClickListener.onClick(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        externalOnClickListener = l;
    }
}
```

Basically `setOnClickListener()` is overriden so that it just stores the passed listener as an instance variable. At construction, the button sets itself as its own on click listener, so that it can receive the on click events, do something, then pass the event on to the stored listener.